# Using wxMathplot with code::blocks

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets, wxmathplot

I am using Code::Blocks with wxWidgets. In general I have a problem similar to that described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761990/how-to-use-mathplot-in-wxsmithcodeblocks-and-wxwidgets). Ok so I copy the `mathplot.h` and `mathplot.cpp` in the project directory, add those files to the project and do `#include mathplot.h` in all automatically generated (not empty project) wxWidgets cpp files. Nevertheless when I try to compile it gives me the error:

```
/usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial/wx/string.h|303|error: ‘wxString::wxString(int)’ is private|
```

How to manage this issue and to finally use wxMathPlot in code::blocks?

This is the compiler log relevant to the error:

```
/usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial/wx/string.h: In member function ‘bool mpWindow::SaveScreenshot(const wxString&, int, wxSize, bool)’:

/usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial/wx/string.h:303:3: error: ‘wxString::wxString(int)’ is private
   wxString(int); 

/home/pekov/Workshop/Code::Blocks/tester/mathplot.cpp:2239:47: error: within this context
     return screenImage.SaveFile(filename, type);
```

Comment: @ravenspoint I add `#include mathplot.h` in the `test_App.cpp` and `test_Main.cpp` that are automatically generated for nonempty wxWidget project (called test) in code::blocks, those also have the corresponding .h files. Nevertheless the project does not compile when I only add the `mathpot.h` and `mathplot.cpp` files and do not use `#include mathplot.h` anywhere.

Comment: "‘wxString::wxString(int)’ is private|" should have more info, in particular "required in this context".  Please post all the information your compiler is providing.

Comment: Yes, I remember this.  mpWindow::SaveScreenshot() no longer works.  Will add my "fix"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mpWindow::SaveScreenshot() no longer works.  Since I do not use the feature, I simply commented out the final line

```
//    return screenImage.SaveFile(filename, type);
```

This allowed my projects to compile and use the other features.

It seems that you are using a version of wxMathPlot that has not been maintained for a long time.  Perhaps you should try downloading [the version on github](https://github.com/mkarmona/wxMathPlot) which looks to be more recent and see how you get on with that.

Comment: Thanks, I did the what you suggested, but now it gives me this:
In file included from /home/pekov/Workshop/Code::Blocks/test_01/mathplot.cpp:36:0:
/home/pekov/Workshop/Code::Blocks/test_01/mathplot.cpp: In member function ‘void mpMovableObject::ShapeUpdated()’:
/usr/include/wx-3.1-unofficial/wx/log.h:1254:5: error: expected id-expression before ‘for’
     for ( bool loopvar = false;